# Rename values in a single column that end with the same string

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have several large data frames with one column (let's call it `timeperiod`) containing text string variables. The variables all end in the same string (`V.1to2` or `V.2to3)`, but the beginnings are different.

I want the values with the same endings changed. As an example:

```
df <- data.frame (Location  = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),
                   timeperiod = c("A.V.1to2", "D.V.1to2", "A.V.1to2","D.V.2to3","A.V.3to4","H.V.3to4","A.V.4to5","D.V.4to5"))
```

As shown:

```
  Location timeperiod
1        a   A.V.1to2
2        b   D.V.1to2
3        c   A.V.1to2
4        d   D.V.2to3
5        e   A.V.3to4
6        f   H.V.3to4
7        g   A.V.4to5
8        h   D.V.4to5
```

***(edit) There a few different data frame types and they all need the timeperiod column changed in a way that assigns numbers in place of the strings however, I oversimplified when I first ask this question. In some cases the number matches the first number in the string, but in other cases it does not match. Here is an updated expected outcome that reflects this situation. ***

My desired outcome would be as follows:

```
df2
  Location timeperiod
1        a          0
2        b          0
3        c          0
4        d          2
5        e          3
6        f          3
7        g          5
8        h          5

df2 <- data.frame (Location  = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),
                  timeperiod = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5))
```

***(edit) With this expected outcome you can see that there are situations where the numbers match the first number in the string but there are other situations in the data where it doesn't match. May apologies for not making this clear in the first example***

Sample code:

```
df$timeperiod[df$timeperiod =="A.V.1to2"] <- "0"
```

Because of the size of my data set and the need to repeat this for multiple data frames with different prefixes for the time period values, I'd like to use `dplyr` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df$timeperiod <- revalue(df$timeperiod, c(ends_with(V.1to2)="0"))
df$timeperiod <- revalue(df$timeperiod, c(ends_with(V.2to3)="2"))
#etc..
```

So I can do it again with different values and sheets. But this doesn't work, and renaming every specific value seems inefficient, so any solution faster than this would serve its purpose.

Comment: Hi @parksnrec1, I think you want to assign the first numerical value as the time period.

Comment: Is "V.XtoY" (last 6 characters from timeperiod) your desired grouping variable?

Comment: Hi @Isa , I think I may have oversimplified my data here. In some cases it is the first numerical value but in other cases this is not true. For example some data frames have a suffix like: V.1to2 and need the timeperiod to be assigned as a 0.

Comment: Hi @GuedesBF , Yes the "V.xtoy" is the variable that groups the values for timeperiod. Thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. In this case, I think my answer does the trick

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_extract`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(timeperiod = str_extract(timeperiod, '\\d+'))
```

```
  Location timeperiod
1        a          1
2        b          1
3        c          1
4        d          2
5        e          3
6        f          3
7        g          4
8        h          4
```

Comment: If the pattern is really that simple, it cant get easier than that! +1

Comment: Thanks @TarJae, I apologize that I didn't explain properly the first time.  I have edited the question and you can see that the first number in the string doesn't match the needed value. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

We can use dplyr, and stringr. First extract the last 6 characters of `timeperiod`. Then, `group_by` timeperiod, and finally use `cur_group_id`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(timeperiod = str_extract(timeperiod, '.{6}$'))%>%
    group_by(timeperiod)%>%
    mutate(timeperiod = cur_group_id())%>%
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 × 2
  Location timeperiod
  <chr>         <int>
1 a                 1
2 b                 1
3 c                 1
4 d                 2
5 e                 3
6 f                 3
7 g                 4
8 h                 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
df <- data.frame (Location  = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),
              timeperiod = c("A.V.1to2", "D.V.1to2", "A.V.1to2","D.V.2to3","A.V.3to4","H.V.3to4","A.V.4to5","D.V.4to5"))

df$timeperiod <- substr(gsub('[[:alpha:]]|[[:punct:]]', '', df$timeperiod), 1, 1)

df

  Location timeperiod
1        a          1
2        b          1
3        c          1
4        d          2
5        e          3
6        f          3
7        g          4
8        h          4
```